# SQL Server Management Studio: new instance for contained database

Tags: sql-server, instance

I'm trying to create a new server instance in SQL Server Management Studio (2008 or 2012) but I can't seem to find how to do it. I have to make this instance for moving a contained database from another instance to the new one. How do I create one and use it?

With kind regards and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sql Server New Instance**

> Just Run the Executable File/Cd that you used to install the Default
>   instance, Name it other than what ever your Existing Instances are
>   called and you are good to go.

**Copy Over the Databases**

> To bring Databases from Other instances you will need to do backups
>   for them databases and Restore on this new Instance.